# constraining the choice of models for uninterpreted functions in Z3

Tags: z3, smt

I a nutshell, I want z3 to verify implications of the form 
`forall x1, x2, ..., xn. exists y1, ..., yn. P => Q`
My difficulty is that I need to obtain the definitions of `y1, ..., yn`  in terms of the variables `x1, ..., xn` that cause the implication to hold.

For example. Suppose I want to check:

`forall x1, x2. exists y. (= x1 (f x2)) => (= x1 (f y))`

I would like to understand that by setting `y` to `x2`, this implication holds.

For this concrete example, I'm trying to do this by asking z3 to give me a model for:

`(declare-fun f (Int) Int)`

`(forall ((_x Int) (_y Int))(exists ((_b Int)) (=> (= _x (f _y)) (= _x (f _b)))))`

However, it is giving me models which instantiate f to 
functions that do not make sense in my case. For instance, functions that 
map all integers to 0. When I tried to constrain the choice of f by asserting that it is surjective, the solver just timed out.

I'm grateful for any help I can get :)

Comment: Did you try disabling MBQI (e.g. via `(set-option :smt.mbqi false)`)?